# Is that possible to get pagination sorting with boolean in Spring data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have a list of item `itemList`, I want to search the database and sort the result by checking if the item is in the `itemList`. So all items in the `itemList` are at top of the rest items.

In `Stream` I can use something like `Stream.of().sorted(Comparator.comparing(itemList::contains))`

How to achieve the same functionality in JPA/Hibernate?

I tried using `Pageable` but it only provides property sorting like

```
Pageable p = PageRequest.of(Sort.by(Sort.Order.by("property"))
findAll(p);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering data with Spring boot CrudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646714/filtering-data-with-spring-boot-crudrepository)