# Filtering Data with PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, pagination, spring-data-jpa, vue-good-table

I have in Vue js vue-good-table that should have pagination, sorting and FILTERING.

From frontend to the backed I pass the following object:

```
@Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class PagingParams {

        private String searchTerm;

        private LinkedHashMap<String, String> columnFilters;

        private LinkedHashMap<String, String> sort;

        private int page;

        private int perPage;
    }
```

Currently paging and sorting works fine:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest
                .of(pagingParams.getPage(), pagingParams.getPerPage(), Sort.by(direction, field));

        Page<Incident> allIncidents = incidentRepository.findAll(pageable);

    public interface IncidentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Incident, Long> {
    ...}
```

But HOW to do filtering? My table has 8 columns and on the top of these columns I can enter some data to filter by different columns. It doesn't make sense to write a plenty of queries to meet different query requirements with different parameters. What is the easiest way to create dynamic queries based on different filter parameters? For example I'have to filter by param1 and param2. Some other time I can get from frontend param4 and param5 to filter by these fields...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering data with Spring boot CrudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646714/filtering-data-with-spring-boot-crudrepository)

Comment: Maybe, but I didn't find the example which is similar to my case when with QueryDsl I can build queries dynamically

Comment: Sorry, but the answer to that thread and the link therein to the Spring Data web extension would allow you to do all of this with pretty much **zero code**. You'd just need to change your front-end to send a query string rather than Json e.g. `/api/incidents?property1=x&property2=Y&page=0&size=20&sort=property3` Spring Data will build the query for you.

Comment: Hmm I use vue-good-table and automatically there is passed such an object. I can change this on frontend but how should my backend in this case? It doesnt change anything...I need to create queries dynamically based on different parameters...

Comment: As I have said, twice. Spring Data supports dynamic predicates via QueryDsl and **the Spring Data Web extension will automatically create the predicate and pageable for you** from the URL request parameters. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe

Comment: Wow, great solution, thank you @AlanHay, I have to try to implement this approach. Thanks!