# Java spring Sort and Filtering

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

So, I am having an assignment with two classes `User` and `Car` with a OneToMany relationship respectively.

I got a task to implement a searching and sorting in the back-end as /cars and /users root endpoints.

Example: - GET `/users?find=Teet&sort=name:asc`

How could I do  that, could you be so kind to specify what are my steps?
I couldn't find any proper explanation at the very moment :(

P.S. I am extending JpaRepository for basic CRUD actions.

Thank You in adnvace! :)

Comment: [Filtering data with Spring boot CrudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646714/filtering-data-with-spring-boot-crudrepository) and [How to do the sorting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering data with Spring boot CrudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646714/filtering-data-with-spring-boot-crudrepository)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring JPA then you can sort the data as

```
  Page<Passenger> page = repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(0, 1, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "seatNumber")));
```

For hibernate criteria , You can use

```
    Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Cat.class);
    c.createAlias("mother.kind", "motherKind");
    c.addOrder(Order.asc("motherKind.value"));
    return c.list();
```