# jpa custom query for multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to create a jpa custom query using joins on few tables to fetch the records.

Here is what I want to achieve:

1. sort data on few parameters(decided on runtime)
2. filter using where clause (decided on runtime)

Example:

@Query(value="Select a.name,b.city,c.reason from user a join address b on a.id=b.id join test c on a.id=c.id

where whereClause1 and whereClause2 //where clause can be single or muliple

order by orderByClause1 asc/desc //decided on runtime which parameter to be used for sorting"

List findData(String whereClause1,String whereClause2,String orderByClause1)

I am not able to create generic query for same.

Any other way is also acceptable for me to solve this problem.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering data with Spring boot CrudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646714/filtering-data-with-spring-boot-crudrepository)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the number of variables in your query you should generate a query by combining all the parameters at runtime and execute the query using [entityManager createQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html) method or you can create query using [hibernate criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria)